# SQL CLR function error

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sqlclr

I've made a SQL CLR function to retrieve data from a SharePoint site. 
This is the part that returns to SQL:

```
public static void GetListItemInfo(
                        object obj,
                        out SqlString Name,
                        out SqlString SO,
                        out SqlString LineNumber,
                        out SqlString SerialNumber,
                        out SqlString Certificates,
                        out SqlString Tags,
                        out SqlString RevisionNumber)
    {
        DataRow r = (DataRow)obj;
        Name = new SqlString(r["ows_LinkFilename"].ToString());
        SO = new SqlString(r["ows_SO"].ToString());
        LineNumber = new SqlString(r["ows_Line_x0020_Number"].ToString());
        SerialNumber = new SqlString(r["ows_Unit_x0020_Number"].ToString());
        Certificates = new SqlString(r["ows_Certificate_x0020_Type"].ToString());
        Tags = new SqlString(r["ows_Tags"].ToString());
        RevisionNumber = new SqlString(r["ows_Revision_x0020_Number"].ToString());
    }
```

All these are the column names that are present on the SharePoint list but when I run the function from SQL it shows this error:

```
Msg 6260, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
An error occurred while getting new row from user defined Table Valued Function : 
System.ArgumentException: Column 'ows_Line_x0020_Number' does not belong to table row.
System.ArgumentException: 
   at System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName)
   at System.Data.DataRow.get_Item(String columnName)
   at SharePointToSQL.GetListItemInfo(Object obj, SqlString& SO, SqlString& LineNumber, SqlString& Tags)
```

But i dont get this error if i try to get just 'SO' and 'Tags' columns, for everything else it doesn't work.

**UPDATE:**
I found out that I'm able to return columns like "ows_SO" "ows_Sample" etc but not columns like "ows_Line_x0020_Number". 
I'm able to do what I want by changing the Column names a bit.
But can anyone tell me why its not possible to use column names like "ows_Line_x0020_Number"??

Comment: apparently your `obj` is missing this field or your field name is wrong

Comment: And Check if these values are not null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xNNNN` notation is used by SharePoint to encode some symbols. `0020` is a HEX for Unicode space, so try to use:

`r["ows_Line Number"]`

instead of

`r["ows_Line_x0020_Number"]`

i.e. replace every `_x0020_` with a  (a space) and see if that helps.

If that doesn't work, try stopping in a debugger and see what actual columns are in the table row. I still think it's just an issue of some row names transformations. To get row names, you can first get shema using `Table` property of `DataRow`, and then us it's [`Columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columns.aspx) property to get all columns names.

Comment: thanks!
it was a problem with the column names changing.
Some columns had a space, some had a 0 in the end and others where cut short.